# Crontab not running expect script

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have an expect script which should upload a file to a sftp server

the expect script work standalone. 
for example , when I run

```
/home/john/bin/mytest.sh
```

works just fine.

---

but when I try to use it with crontab , it doesn't work

### tmp/crontab

```
1  * * * * /usr/bin/expect -f /home/john/bin/mytest.sh
```

---

### My script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
spawn sftp  john@johncdq.com
expect "password:"
send “@user[as\n”
expect "sftp>"
send "cd batch/unp\n"
expect "sftp>"
send " put /home/john/newbin/NY010120120717.dat\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
expect eof
exit
```

Comment: please explain "doesn't work"

Comment: `-f` is missing at end of `#!`-line.

Answer (score -1):

First, be sure you are enable to run cron:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
See the **Enable User Level Cron** section

Second, try to enclose the command with "

```
1  * * * * "/usr/bin/expect -f /home/john/bin/mytest.sh"
```

Or better, let Make an **Expect script** executable as a standalone program, you must do two things:
1- Make the script executable.
 
2- Supply the path to the script for expect . The path on my system is: /usr/bin/expect ; therefore, enter that path on the first line of your script with a preceding “shebang” (#! ):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

And change the cron jobs to:

```
1  * * * * /home/john/bin/mytest.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the expect interpreter from the crontab line and write it like that (I usually name my expect scripts with the extension .exp, I don't know if it matters):

```
* * * * * /home/john/bin/mytest.sh
```

As you have the line #!/usr/bin/expect in your script you don't need to write it again in your command line. Besides, the second parameter in crontab is the name of the user who run the script and not the interpreter. I have written an (*) in the first position because I guess that you want to run the script every minute, if you write a (1)  your script will only run on thw first minute in every hour. I hope it can help.